# Confusion with Users in Rundeck

Tags: linux, daemon, jobs, rundeck

I am a quite new with Rundeck and I am confusing with Users in Rundeck configuration, in Rundeck server and in Rundeck node.

I have read all official documentation and I understand Users definition in Rundeck's daemon. However, I don't know if a new user (called for example rundeck) is needed in Rundeck server to execute the daemon or it is created when Rundeck is installed with rpm. So, I don't know which user is used by Rundeck's daemon to executed.

Another question I have is if a rundeck user (may be with sudo privileges depending jobs) is needed in nodes to execute jobs. I think the user that Rundeck uses to logging on the Node is the user it use to execute jobs. This means a rundeck user has to be added in all nodes.

Could someone answer my questions? 
Thanks beforehand, regards

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user account that runs the Rundeck service depends on the install type. System packaged instances (like from .deb and .rpm) will automatically create a service account called "rundeck" to run the daemon process.

The user account used for remote execution is defined by the Node via the "username" attribute. Some Rundeck users have a common service account for all the remote executions but others use an already existing account on those remote hosts. That is just your convention.

Comment: Thanks!! I have been working with Rundeck since I posted this question and with your answer is everything understanding. :)